# XSSFWorkbook or XSSFSheet not working with Maven

Tags: maven, apache-poi

I have set up a class using XSSFWorkbook and XSSFSheet. But I don't get an option to import the libraries even though the following dependencies are added to the pom.xml.

Below is my pom.xml dependencies:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml-schemas -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-excelant -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-excelant</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlbeans/xmlbeans -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>




<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/dom4j/dom4j -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Where are you expecting to find an import option? What error do you get if you do the import anyway?

Comment: Usually, when I click on it it shows the option to import. It doesn't do it for XSSFWorkbook. Error is "XSSFWorkbook cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: Maven is a command line tool, so you probably aren't clicking on anything in Maven...

Comment: it is not on maven, it on the actual program code where I use XSSFWorkbbok that I'm clicking on

Answer (score -1):

```
requires poi
requires poi.ooxml
requires poi.ooxml.schemas
```